# Where can I find an ontology of algebraic structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, meta-math

- A group is a monoid where every element admits an inverse,
- A ring is a monoid under multiplication that distributes over a commutative group
- A field is a ring whose non-zero elements form a group under multiplication
- and so on...

These type of relationships form an [ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_language) of algebraic structures. Is there a formal ontology of mathematics available somewhere, perhaps in the OWL/RDF format?

edit: to give you an idea of the motivation, it would be nice to automatically extract dependency graph for an algebraic structure. I quickly [drew an (incomplete) one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb6ac.jpg) for an Abelian variety.

Comment: What do you mean by ontology here? What about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algebraic_structures ?

Comment: I provided a link that describes what I mean by ontology. These two Wikipedia article are a good start, but I'm looking for something much deeper. For instance, can you tell me, offhand, from the list what are all the structures involved in describing an Abelian variety?

Comment: I am not sure that this question leads to something deep, as you say. The "graph" for an abelian variety is nice (but not deep).

Comment: I mean "deep" in the sense of "thorough", not "profound". My Abelian Variety graph isn't thorough at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at our [OntoMathPro](http://ontomathpro.org), a crowdsourced ontology of professional-level mathematics, covering a wide range of topics including algebra.

Comment: How are the classes related? For [example](http://ontomathpro.org/ontology/E130___536385546.html) just tells you a single direction, not how, and is without reference to the smaller components that make up the class.

Answer (score 1):

I have two similar graphs at pages 1 and 24 of [my BSc thesis](https://amslaurea.unibo.it/4160/1/allegro_matteo_tesi.pdf).

One online resource listing many algebraic structures by their properties is [MathStructures](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/) on chapman.edu.

Also, [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) for the group-like structures.